# select only specific fields in joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to specify the fields that you want in the left joined table

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM students
LEFT OUTER JOIN classes_enrolled (can i specify fields here)
ON students.student_id = classes_enrolled.student_id
```

I only wanted to get the field **subject** from the left joined table **classes_enrolled** rather than have * all the fields in the matched rows being appended

Comment: Try `SELECT students.*, classes_enrolled.subject` ...

Comment: actually you can specify it on `SELECT`

Comment: But in your case it will only return rows from student table. So what is issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try something like

```
SELECT  students.* ,
        classes_enrolled.subject 
FROM    students LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        classes_enrolled  ON students.student_id = classes_enrolled.student_id
```

It is actually considered good practice to specify the field names, rather than using `SELECT *`

Answer (score 1):

you can choose any of these:

using subquery to select on specified columns,

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    students
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  student_id, subject 
            FROM    classes_enrolled
        ) b ON students.student_id = b.student_id
```

or the one that I prefer -- to manually select these columns,

```
SELECT  students.*,
        classes_enrolled.subject 
FROM    students
        LEFT OUTER JOIN classes_enrolled 
            ON students.student_id = classes_enrolled.student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below
SELECT , classes_enrolled.subject,  * FROM students, 
LEFT OUTER JOIN classes_enrolled 
ON students.student_id = classes_enrolled.student_id